# Change Azure Resource Group with a backup attached

Tags: azure, azure-resource-group

I'm trying to move a disk from a resource group to another one(with the same region) and I get an error telling me it's attached to a Azure Backup job. "Resource X are being backed up as part of a Azure Backup job"

The backup is set in a Recovery Vault.
I tried to stop the backup and delete the data in it (it's a dev environment) and I still get this error.

Is there something I am missing?

Thanks,

Comment: did you try this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-manage-vms

Comment: ya that's exactly what I did. That being said, these delete operations are still soft delete since I have 14 days to "undelete". Maybe the move could wotk in 14 days... Best scenario still would be to change de resource group without deleting any backup..

Comment: If you click on hidden items in the All Resources list, you can see the RestorePointCollections. Seems like what I need to delete. Job is running since 30mins and nothing happening..